# Is Clojure concurrency support still disabled on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure

In a recent [blog post](http://www.adrianmouat.com/bit-bucket/2012/08/clojure-and-google-app-engine/), Adrian Mouat said that App Engine doesn't support Clojure concurrency, such as agents. However, [GAE Java supports threads](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) as of the App Engine 1.6.4 release.

Is the Clojure concurrency model fully supported on App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

I know one would have to use their [Thread Manager API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager) for thread creation. For appengine front ends each created thread would still be tied to the current request. On an appengine back end you would be able to make  background thread would persist after the request was handled. I do not know about other libraries,but appengine-magic has not been updated since Google App Engine SDK 1.6.3.1 release with little activity on the forks,but updating it to the latest appengine api was a [summer of code project proposal for 2012](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Google+Summer+of+Code+2012#GoogleSummerofCode2012-appengine-magicenhancementsforGoogleAppEngine).